# Troubles with Angular CLI installing

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, angular, angular-cli

I have installed node (v 8.5.0) with npm (5.3.0).
After that I made: npm install -g @angular/cli but it doesn't work:

```
ng help
-bash: ng: command not found
```

here are installation logs:

```
MacBook-Air:~ michael$ npm install -g @angular/cli
/Users/michael/.npm-global/bin/ng -> /Users/michael/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
+ @angular/cli@1.4.3
updated 1 package in 39.276s
```

Comment: see your node version. Is it installed correctly?

Comment: michael$ node -v
v8.5.0

Comment: **node** and **npm** works correctly, but **ng** command doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1186) on github.
  It seems like they are running `npm install` again possibly needing admin privileges as well.

Comment: looks like I have to reset my mac to factory settings and try again